# Multiple JOIN and GROUP BY: What is the issue with my query?

Tags: sql, join, group-by

If I run my query like this:

```
select 
    Sys.1,Sys.2,Sys.3,
    DDD.a,DDD.b,DDD.c,
    Gen.x,Gen.y,Gen.z 
from sys_table Sys 
join ddd_table DDD on (Sys.3=DDD.a) 
join gen_table Gen on (DDD.a=Gen.x) 
where 
    Sys.1 = 'string' 
    AND Sys.2 = 1 
    AND Sys.3 = 1 
GROUP BY a
```

I get an error 'Ambiguous column name 'a'.

If I specify the table like here:

```
select 
    Sys.1,Sys.2,Sys.3,
    DDD.a,DDD.b,DDD.c,
    Gen.x,Gen.y,Gen.z 
from sys_table Sys 
join ddd_table DDD on (Sys.3=DDD.a) 
join gen_table Gen on (DDD.a=Gen.x) 
where 
    Sys.1 = 'string' 
    AND Sys.2 = 1 
    AND Sys.3 = 1 
GROUP BY DDD.a
```

I get the error: Column 'sys_table.1' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

What am I missing?

Comment: You've fixed one syntax error, and found another that was hidden by the first.  As your error message says, if you `SELECT a, b, c` then you can't just `GROUP BY a`, you'd need `GROUP BY a, b, c` or `SELECT a, SUM(b), SUM(c)`.  Can you give example input and output data, sufficient to demonstrate the behaviour you want to accomplish?

Comment: Without the Group by I receive 6 rows containing 2 different data. So e.g. 2 rows of same data, and 4 rows same data. I want to have two rows, one from each kind, meaning I need 1 row/'DDD.a' value. Is that clear?

Comment: Please.  Show.  Some.  Example.  Data.  Both the input and output?

Comment: You can only have group by columns in the select clause plus any aggregates (sum,count,min,max,etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sam yi is correct.  The group by must be by all columns that are not part of an aggregate.  Some engines allow this loosely to just grab the first instance of the column from whatever table if it is not an aggregate or part of the group by.  Since you don't even have any aggregates, you can just apply a "max()" against each one, and if the values are never changing and would be the same across the board, should be no impact.

Also, having column names as just a number (I didnt even think was allowed), is IMO a very bad thing to deal with, but believe this is only because you are hiding actual content in relation to the REAL problem you are encountering.

```
select 
      DDD.a,
      max( Sys.1 ) as `1`,
      max( Sys.2 ) as `2`,
      max( Sys.3 ) as `3`,
      max( DDD.b ) as b,
      max( DDD.c ) as c,
      max( Gen.x ) as x,
      max( Gen.y ) as y,
      max( Gen.z ) as z 
   from 
      sys_table Sys 
         join ddd_table DDD on (Sys.3 = DDD.a) 
            join gen_table Gen on (DDD.a = Gen.x) 
   where 
          Sys.1 = 'string' 
      AND Sys.2 = 1 
      AND Sys.3 = 1 
   GROUP BY 
      DDD.a
```

Comment: of course I'm not using numbers as column names, it's just an example

Answer (score 1):

The first error appears probably because the field name "a" exists in more than one tables. In the second query you need to group with all the fields you are selecting (actually you don't need to group at all, there's no meaning to group to all your fields since you don't use an aggregate function).
Hence, your select will be:

```
select 
Sys.1,Sys.2,Sys.3,DDD.a,DDD.b,DDD.c,Gen.x,Gen.y,Gen.z 
from 
sys_table Sys 
join ddd_table DDD on (Sys.3=DDD.a) 
join gen_table Gen on (DDD.a=Gen.x) 
where 
Sys.1 = 'string' AND Sys.2 = 1 AND Sys.3 = 1
```

Comment: Grouping without any aggregate functions isn't completely meaningless... it eliminates duplicates. You can remove the `GROUP BY` but you have to add a `DISTINCT` to keep the identical meaning.

Comment: I have already tried to use distinct only for DDD.a but I get syntax error: `SELECT Sys.1,Sys.2,Sys.3,DISTINCT(DDD.a),DDD.b...`etc